# Find indices of String in List - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've got a following input:

```
["56", "+", "49", "-", "2", "+", "15]
```

So it is a list of Strings and I would like get indices of "+" - [1, 5]. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `zip` and a list comprehension.

```
indicesOf :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
indicesOf a as = [i | (b, i) <- zip as [0..], b == a]
```

Zipping with `[0..]` is a standard way to label every element with an index, and then it's a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`elemIndices`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndices) already exists in `Data.List`

```
elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
```

as

```
>>> elemIndices "+" ["56","+","49","-","2","+","15"]
[1,5]
```